# Subprojectivity of the spaces $B_{p}(1<p<\infty)$

Tags: banach-spaces

Fix $1<p<\infty$. In his thesis, C.J.Seifert adapted the construction of Baerstein's space $B$ by replacing the number 2 by $p$ to construct the space, called "$B_{p}$" space. He showed that every infinite-dimensional closed subspace $Y$ of $B_{p}$ contains a subspace $Z$ isomorphic to $l_{p}$ and complemented in $B_{p}$.

My question: Does the subspace $Z$ can be chosen to be $\lambda_{p}$-complemented in $B_{p}$? where the constant $\lambda_{p}$ depends only on $p$.

Since I do not have Seifert's thesis, I am not sure my question is true.

Thank you!

Comment: To be honest I think that nobody answers this question not because it is not known how to handle it, but because (1) It does not seem to be explicitly answered in standard references; (2) Working it out requires nontrivial amount of time; (3) It is the most natural if this time will be spend by a person who needs the answer. As for techniques needed: (1) Use block-bases; (2) To get $\ell_p$-bases consider block bases for which the maximal coordinate is repeated many times; (3) Estimate the norms of projections on subspaces of this type.

Comment: Yes!  So in the book of P.G.Casazza and T.J.Shura (Tsirelson's space), Seifert's results are only listed and their proofs are not given. Thanks, Mikhail.

Comment: Can you remind us the definition of BP?

Comment: @Ben I suggest to look at Baernstein's paper http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm42/sm4217.pdf and replace $2$ by $p$ in formula (1) there.

Comment: By the way, the thesis is called *Averaging in Banach Spaces* and is available at the Kent State University Library. Coincidentally, two years ago I emailed them about it and they told me it would cost about $18 to send a photocopied version of it to me. So, that's an option.

Comment: Oh, and while you would think an electronic copy would be cheaper, it's actually much more expensive: 5 dollars per page plus a 10 dollar service fee, and the thesis is 48 pages.  Yikes!